# Book about a woman with Godly insight hiding among Christians from demons that come to Earth in a pyramid

Tags: story-identification, books, christian

I'm looking for a Christian scifi thriller with a hooded black-robed figure on cover.

It's about aliens coming to Earth in a pyramid, saying they are our creators, but they are really demons. A woman dreams about them beforehand, so her reporter husband sneaks aboard and the demons kill him.

She hides out with other believers, because she has Godly insight dreams and she's helping them. Then the demons end up killing all the believers that are hiding out with her, all except two and one is a guy who wasn't a believer, but is becoming one, and who the next book is about.

It's a three book series, I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Well I found it at a thrift shop I just read it last yr I remember it being a bit older of a book somewhere between 2002 & 2014 I can't remember unfortunately I do remember the aliens/demons saying we all come from 1 creator & we are their ancestors and implementing the mark on ppl and the husband of the woman w the dreams sneaking onboard the pyramid to make sure his wife is right and the demons kill him  only the ppl they elected non believers where aloud on board and they were given the option to go home w the aliens but inorder to do so all ppl had to give up their faith or none could go

Comment: I also remember that the demons find the hideout of the Christians and kill them all on crosses except the 2 who got away a man and a woman

Comment: I'm read it in the middle of the USA  